# C++ function call identifier

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Consider the following code:

```
void Foo() {
  ......
  LOG_ERROR("I'm error 1")   // call 1
  .....
  LOG_ERROR("I'm error 2")  // call 2
  .....

}
```

`LOG_ERROR()` is a macro. `LOG_ERROR()` should print string identifying it
in code, while the assumption is that code can change, but `A::Foo()`
will remain unchanged. The identifier should retain while code
changes.

This can be solved by adding error code as argument to `LOG_ERROR()`,
but we want to remove from the programmer the burden to manage error
codes.

Using `__LINE__` is not an answer, since `Foo()` can move from build to
build.

Therefore I thought about identifying `LOG_ERROR()` relative to start of
`Foo()`:

- a. Identify by file name (`__FILE__`) + function name (`__FUNCTION__`) +
  line number of `LOG_ERROR()` relative to `Foo()` start.
- b. Identify by file name (`__FILE__`) + function name (`__FUNCTION__`) +
  `LOG_ERROR()` call number in `Foo()`.

The solution should be work with VC++ 2008 and g++ 4.1.1 at least.

One proposed solution ([link text](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/bf4abc4fc9f023a1#)) is:

```
#define ENABLE_LOG_ERROR static const int LOG_ERROR_start_line = __LINE__
#define LOG_ERROR(s) cerr << "error #" << (__LINE__ - LOG_ERROR_start_line) \
    << " in " << __func__ << ": " << s << endl

void Foo() {
     ENABLE_LOG_ERROR;
     //...
     LOG_ERROR("error 1");
     int i;
     LOG_ERROR("error 2");
}
```

This will force user to write `ENABLE_LOG_ERROR` in start of each function containing
`LOG_ERROR()` and there're many such functions.

Is there other way to accomplish the task?

Comment: @idimba, if it's not too much trouble, you can use a script to automatic add `ENABLE_LOG_ERROR;` right after every function name. I use that trick when I *explore* 3rd party code.

Comment: Nice idea, but it will influence __LINE__ which we extensive use in our logging sub sustem.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is **non-standard**, but both MSVC and GCC support `__COUNTER__`, which is incremented every time it is invoked.

```
#define LOG_ERROR(s) cerr << "error #" << (__COUNTER__) << " in " \
<< __func__ << ": " << s << endl
```

Note that `__COUNTER__` will be reset in each compilation unit, and ONLY in each compilation unit. So if `Foo()` has 7 `LOG_ERROR()` macros, in a later function `Bar()` the value of `__COUNTER__` will be 7 for the first use of `LOG_ERROR()`.

Comment: Actual problem is that if you insert a new message, the ones below it are all renumbered.

Comment: @GMan: You're correct that it won't reset for each function. I've edited to clarify that.

@Earwicker: Also correct. This is a fairly brittle solution. It assumes that `LOG_ERROR()`s are only ever added after all previous invocations in the same compilation unit.

Comment: The problem is that __COUINTER__ is only supported from gcc 4.3.3, while I'm using 4.1.1

Comment: technically cpp is the pre-processor, so you could try updating just that to get support for __COUNTER__

Answer (score 1):

While the question is about ways to generate unique line identifiers within a function for logging purposes, I'm going to take a step back and look at the actual problem to be solved: How to generate log output which can easily identify the source code line without putting the burden on the writer of the code.

Let's assume you are embedding a unique build version in each release of your program (which is a good idea in general). Let's also assume you are using a source code control mechanism which keeps the history of your source code (which is also a very good idea to be doing anyway) and which can present you with the source as it was for any requested build version of the program.

If those assumptions hold true, then a solution is to have your program write it's current version into the log file. Then each individual logging entry can simply record the line number via `__LINE__`.

Thus, when someone needs to use the log: they can look at the version number in the log, grab the corresponding source from the source code control repository, and use the line numbers from the log to go to the proper source lines. This puts a bit more burden on the person using the log output. However, if logged code depends on or is influenced by other code which could change from version to version, then the historical state of the source code might be required anyway.

Furthermore, a benefit of working this way is that it removes to need to assume that any given function will remain unchanged, as was originally part of the question. So this method has a much broader application.

---

As far as implementation goes, you could either log the program version when the program starts up or you could make the logging macro include it in each entry.

If the program version is normally stored somewhere not easily accessible in normal source code, then you could create a pre-build step which would extract the version and write it into a simple version.h file as a #define or const string. Then the logging code or macro could automatically use that to always output the current version of the program.

Answer (score 0):

By modification of the stack idea, use a `std::map` mapping from `std::string` to the count, and look-up the function name.

```
std::map<std::string, int> LOG_ERROR_count_map;
#define LOG_ERROR(s) {\
  int count = ++LOG_ERROR_count_map[ __func__ ];\
  std::cout << count << " in " __func__ ": " s << std::endl;\
}
```

This means you don't need the `ENABLE_LOG_ERROR`, but at the cost of a map look-up for each log. (It's a trade-off between ease-of-use and time.)

Comment: Both my solution and GMan's don't give the nth instance of LOG_ERROR in the function, but the nth call of LOG_ERROR in the function. Therefore they cannot be used to simply count down the uses (which is probably the intended use) when branching occurs. Any form of dynamic count method will not work.

Comment: It's probably obvious, but worth pointing out that you can't use the preprocessor for static counts based on function name because there's no way to detect when the function has changed - strings cannot be compared.